# How i can enable WordPress Posts Pagination

Tags: php, wordpress, pagination

How i can enable pagination in my page (template page wordpress)

**My Code**

```
<?php
$catquery = new WP_Query( 'cat=2&posts_per_page=10' );
while($catquery->have_posts()) : $catquery->the_post();
?>
<div>
  <br />
<div class="news"><!-- Start News Box -->
<div class="img_news"><!-- Start Image News -->
<?php
$url_thumb = wp_get_attachment_url( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID) );
?>
<img class="img_thumbs" title="" alt="" src="<?php echo $url_thumb; ?>">
</div><!-- End Image News -->
<div class="title_news"><!-- Start Title News -->
<h2>
<?php the_title(); ?>
</h2>
<div class="details">
<?php the_content_limit(500, "Read More..."); ?>
</div>
</div><!-- End Title News -->
<hr>
</div><!-- End News Box -->
</div>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

I am using this but i can't see the pagination bar : example (1-2-3-...-100)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to add 'paged' attribute in argument($catquery).

```
$paged = ( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) ? absint( get_query_var( 'paged' ) ) : 1;
$catargs = array('cat'=>'2','posts_per_page'=>10,'paged' => $paged);

$catquery = new WP_Query( $catargs);
while($catquery->have_posts()) : $catquery->the_post();
//do stuff
endwhile;

$big = 999999999; 
echo paginate_links( array(
    'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
    'format' => '?paged=%#%',
    'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
    'total' => $catquery->max_num_pages,
    'prev_text'          => __( 'Previous page', 'twentyfifteen' ),
    'next_text'          => __( 'Next page', 'twentyfifteen' ),
) );
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add these pagination functions before or after your loop (before or after the `while` loop):

```
<div class="nav-previous alignleft"><?php next_posts_link( 'Older posts' ); ?></div>
<div class="nav-next alignright"><?php previous_posts_link( 'Newer posts' ); ?></div>
```

Have a look at Wordpress' documentation [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Pagination).